SQL Server job execution status run check never completes
I have a process where I check for SQL Server agent job execution status making sure all the jobs in question have their last run for the given date completed reporting either success or failure. Based on the outcome of the last run I either execute downstream jobs on success or abort on failure. I have this process which waits for a minute and then loops through all the specified jobs until all are complete.
The problem I run into is when I investigate the job activity monitor I see all the jobs complete either reporting success or failure. But, my query does not complete. Its stuck in this infinite loop.
Is there any better approach than what I'm already doing to address this.
SQL:
BEGIN

    DECLARE @noofjob INT;
    DECLARE @failedjob VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @jobnames TABLE (name VARCHAR(255)); -- To store job names
    DECLARE @jobname VARCHAR(MAX) = 'child_job_1,child_job_2,child_job_3,child_job_4,child_job_5';

    -- Copy SQL Agent job history into a temp table
        SELECT  jh.[instance_id],
        jh.[job_id],
        j.[name],
        j.[description],
        jh.[step_id],
        jh.[step_name],
        jh.[sql_message_id],
        jh.[sql_severity],
        jh.[message],
        jh.[run_status],
        CASE WHEN jh.[run_status] = 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
             WHEN jh.[run_status] = 0 THEN 'Failed'
             WHEN jh.[run_status] = 2 THEN 'Canceled'
             ELSE 'Unknown'
         END AS [run_status_description],
        jh.[run_date],
        jh.[run_time],
        msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(jh.run_date, jh.run_time) AS 'run_date_time',
        jh.[run_duration],
        jh.[operator_id_emailed],
        jh.[operator_id_netsent],
        jh.[operator_id_paged],
        jh.[retries_attempted],
        jh.[server]
   INTO #jobhistory
   FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] jh
   JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] j 
     ON j.[job_id] = jh.[job_id]
    
    -- Insert job names into table variable
    INSERT INTO @jobnames(name)
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@jobname, ',');

    -- Count number of distinct jobs
    SELECT @noofjob = COUNT(*) FROM @jobnames;

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        -- Drop temp table if it exists
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #lastrun;

        -- Get latest run information
        SELECT name, MAX(run_date_time) AS latest_run
        INTO #lastrun
        FROM #jobhistory
        WHERE run_date_time > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        AND name IN (SELECT name FROM @jobnames)
        GROUP BY name;

        -- Check if all jobs have run in the last 6 hours
        IF @noofjob != (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name)
            FROM #jobhistory
            WHERE run_date_time > DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETDATE())
            AND name IN (SELECT name FROM @jobnames)
        )
        BEGIN
            -- Wait for 1 minute before checking again
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Find failed jobs
            SET @failedjob = (
                SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ',')
                FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT s.name
                    FROM #jobhistory S
                    JOIN #lastrun lr
                        ON S.name = lr.name
                        AND S.run_date_time = lr.latest_run
                    WHERE S.run_status != 1 -- '1' denotes success
                ) AS FailedJobs
            );

            -- Check if there are any failed jobs
            IF LEN(@failedjob) > 0
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR ('Stored procedure execution stopped due to failed job: %s', 16, 1, @failedjob);
                THROW 50010, 'Error', 1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Wait for 30 seconds before the next check
                WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';
            END

            -- Exit loop once all conditions are met
            BREAK;
        END
    END
END


You need to add RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/03/11/sql-server-printing-status-using-raiserror-nowait-option/ throughout your code to identify which part of the loop it's stuck and what the state is. I also suggest using sp_whoisactive to work out if there is a lock stopping a query from returning.

sysjobhistory is your table different from mine? It doesn't contains name column. Also, WHERE run_date > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) is kinda weird because run_date is an INT, i hope you didn't get ChatGPT to write this code for you, because it's beyond bad

It seems like the built in SQL Agent Job (via SSMS) functionality can do what you need.  Each step within a job supports "retry attempts" and a "retry interval". It also supports different options when the step completes with success or failure. It also supports logging.

@siggemannen, I updated my OP. I am combining the resultset of sysjobs & sysjobhistory into a temporary table which now has the job name and run_date_time as datetime datatype.
